# what is the context in swift?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

I am new in swift . let' try to understand `closures`
declare a function like closures:

```
let sayHello = {
  return "hello"
}
```

> unable to infer closures return type of current context ()->()

My question is here what is the context ?

```
let sayHello : String  = {
      return "hello"
    }
```

> Function produce expected type of "string" , did you mean to  call it  with ()

honestly i did not understand this error ?  anyone help me to understand and why need to specify this one  `()`

however . this is working fine and without error it is called closures

```
 let sayHello : String  = {
          return "hello"
        }()
```

thank you

Answer (score 2):

The context the error message refers to means the initialization statement for the closure, along with its surrounding.

Swift can often *infer* (figure out from things that it already knows) the type of closure, without requiring you to specify it explicitly.

For example, if you are calling a function that takes a closure taking an `Int` as its argument, Swift figures out that the type of your closure's argument must be an `Int`. Similarly, if your closure returns a captured local variable of type `String`, Swift does not need you to specify the return type, because it figures it must be `String` as well.

None of this works when you create closures for future use, and assign them to a variable. In situations like that you need to tell Swift what kind of closure you are creating:

```
let sayHello : ()->String = {
    return "hello"
}
```

Now you have a variable `sayHello` of type "a closure that takes no arguments and returns a `String`" (i.e. `()->String` closure). You can call it later to say hello:

```
let hello = sayHello()
```

**Note:** Your example that "worked" also defined a closure. However, the closure was used immediately after its definition, and then discarded.

Comment: Note that single expression closures can have their types inferred, e.g `let sayHello = { return "hello" }`.